INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error
I use a ASUS ZenBook Flip 13 as daily driver for 1.5 years.
One year ago I had the first blue screen with the INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error. After the restart everything returned to normal, I thought it was just a random glitch.
In the last month this happened twice, today is the third time. The laptop works well in general, with the exception of the times when the error appears, it manifests itself through a complete freeze, then a blue screen. Sometimes it recovers immediately after restarting, sometimes when starting it enters the bios and displays no storage present and only after several restart attempts it recovers. Once it recovered after a few hours after being left off.
I ran different tests to identify problems, CHKDSK, memtest, Hard Disk Sentinel, system stress test, etc. All the tests were passed successfully and I didn't have a blue screen.
I don't understand what the problem is and I'm afraid of losing the data on the device. I made a backup, but because it's my laptop that I use daily, data is constantly being added/modified.
Is it safe to continue using it? What could be the problem?

S.M.A.R.T data:    

C:\Windows\System32>wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus
Active  InstanceName                                                    
PredictFailure  Reason TRUE    
SCSI\Disk&Ven_NVMe&Prod_WDC_PC_SN730_SDB\4&1d2cd6e8&0&020000_0  FALSE           0




It can happen if a USB device is attached, and on boot, it tries to boot from that instead of the normal internal drive. Its also possible the cable to the drive is faulty and sometimes fails.

BTW, by "backup", I hope you meant a full drive image.  If the drive is faulty, you can replace it with a new one and simply restore that image in a matter of minutes. Otherwise, you'd need to restore all your old applications, one at a time, then customize the PC and restore the data - A PIA (Painstaking, Intensive and Arduous task).

S.M.A.R.T data is required - please install smartmontools → Open an Admin terminal within %ProgramFiles%\smartmontools\bin, run a short S.M.A.R.T test: smartctl -t short /dev/<disk>; sleep 125; smartctl -a /dev/<disk> → Please post S.M.A.R.T output from the third command within a code box in your question → Run a long S.M.A.R.T test: smartctl -t long /dev/<disk> (check progress occasionally by smartctl -a /dev/<disk> | FindStr "remaining") → Once its completed, please replace S.M.A.R.T output in your question

Thank you all for your support.
@JW0914 Unfortunately, I was unable to obtain the S.M.A.R.T. data. using the suggested software. I use windows 11 and the suggested commands gave me an error. I tried to adapt the commands to my system. The command smartctl --scan displays: /dev/sda -d ata # /dev/sda, ATA device. Running smartctl -t short -d ata /dev/sda I receive the error Read Device Identity failed: Input/output error .
@DrMoishe Pippik What software do you recommend for full image backup?
@LPChip No USB device is connected at boot.

@Adrian What output do you receive when running smartctl -a /dev/sda (it should resemble this). The device type shouldn't need to be specified (if the drive was connected through a USB to SATA converter cable, it likely would, but not when the drive is directly connected to the motherboard). smartctl is the default software to obtain S.M.A.R.T data

@JW0914 smartctl -a /dev/sda displays Read Device Identity failed: Input/output error If this is a USB connected device, look at the various --device=TYPE variants A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options. You're right, I don't understand why I'm getting the error. The storage is not connected via USB, it is the SSD that came with the laptop from the factory.

I forgot to add a screenshot with the error.
